# How can I remove rows that contain more than two 0 values?

Tags: r, select, filter

Suppose I have the following dataset:

| **ID** | **Col_A** | **Col_B** | **Col_C** | **Col_D** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 0 | 20 | 5 |
| 2 | 20 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 4 | 15 | 10 | 15 | 5 |

Which function in R can I use to get rid of rows that have more than two "0"-values, so that the output results in:

| **ID** | **Col_A** | **Col_B** | **Col_C** | **Col_D** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 0 | 20 | 5 |
| 2 | 20 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | 15 | 10 | 15 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical vector with `rowSums` to `subset` the data

```
subset(df1, rowSums(df1[-1] == 0) < 3)
  ID Col_A Col_B Col_C Col_D
1  1    30     0    20     5
2  2    20     0    10     0
4  4    15    10    15     5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Col_A = c(30L, 20L, 0L, 15L), Col_B = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 10L), Col_C = c(20L, 10L, 0L, 15L), Col_D = c(5L, 0L, 
10L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```